# Python : how to create stacked graph withTitanic Dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python and working with Titanic Dataset to create a stacked chart using for loop. Can anyone suggest to me how to convert from bar to stacked? What option should be changed for the below code?

```
df.drop(["name","ticket","cabin","boat","body","home.dest"], axis=1,inplace=True)

df.embarked = df.embarked.fillna(df.embarked.mode()[0])

es_grp1=df.groupby(['embarked','survived'])

for i in es_grp1.groups.keys():
    plt.bar(str(i),es_grp1.get_group(i).embarked.size)
    plt.text(str(i),es_grp1.get_group(i).embarked.size,es_grp1.get_group(i).embarked.size)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html use the `bottom` keyword for each successive bar to place it on top of the previous one as shown

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I got it. But if I use a for loop inside to go each of the variable then how to re do the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to judge without seeing exactly how your data are structured, but based on the link I've provided this should work ok. If you can show what the data actually look like then that might make this clearer.

```
df.drop(["name","ticket","cabin","boat","body","home.dest"], axis=1,inplace=True)

df.embarked = df.embarked.fillna(df.embarked.mode()[0])

es_grp1=df.groupby(['embarked','survived'])
value_sum = 0
for i in es_grp1.groups.keys():
    plt.bar(0,es_grp1.get_group(i).embarked.size, bottom=value_sum)
    value_sum += es_grp1.get_group(i).embarked.size
    plt.text(str(i),es_grp1.get_group(i).embarked.size,es_grp1.get_group(i).embarked.size)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I've re written the code and its working.